# Axios deprecated concurrent requests?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, axios

Currently the axios readme says this unhelpfully formatted section:

> **Concurrency (Deprecated)**
>
> Please use Promise.all to replace the below
> functions.
>
> Helper functions for dealing with concurrent requests.
>
> axios.all(iterable) axios.spread(callback)

So is .all and .spread deprecated or is the use of Promise.all to replace the other methods deprecated? Is concurrency itself deprecated?
What's the recommended method of concurrent request handling?

Answer (score 5):

As it says, they have deprecated their own `axios.all(iterable)` and `axios.spread(callback)` functions, instead recommending you use JS's new in-built [`Promise.all(iterable)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function, which does almost the same thing: takes an iterable of promises as an input, and returns a single Promise that resolves to an array of the results of the input promises.

The concurrency example in the [README](https://github.com/axios/axios#example) is as follows:

```
function getUserAccount() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345');
}

function getUserPermissions() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345/permissions');
}

Promise.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(function (results) {
    const acct = results[0];
    const perm = results[1];
  });
```

Comment: An example would be helpful here.

Comment: Edited to add the example from their documentation.